# onMouseOver not triggering specific function

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I'm having a very confusing issue and I was wondering if someone could shed some light on it.

I have a DIV element ...

```
<div onmouseout="scrollRight();" onmouseover="scrollLeft();" id="rightScrollRegion" class="ScrollRegion"></div>
```

And an external script file that has ...

```
function scrollLeft(){
        document.getElementById('rightScrollRegion').style.background = "#0000ff";
    }

    function scrollRight(){
        document.getElementById('rightScrollRegion').style.background = "#ff0000";
    }
```

The problem is that the onmouseover does not seem to call the function scrollLeft(); or scrollRight();  I don't seem to understand where I made an error.

I did some testing to see if it was something in the function...

window.onload = function(){

```
scrollLeft();
```

}

Works in the external file and changes the DIV's background when the pageloads ... so function works.

I also tried changing what's called in onmouseover ...

```
<div onmouseover="alert('Hello');" id="rightScrollRegion" class="ScrollRegion"></div>
```

prints an alert window just fine.

So I thought maybe I couldn't change the background using onmouseover so I tried ...

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.background = '#0000ff'" id="rightScrollRegion" class="ScrollRegion"></div>
```

And that changes the background as expected.

But for some reason I can't get my function to trigger on the DIV.  I've search all over the internet and I haven't been unable to find a solution to the issue.  I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.  I've used external functions in other sites but never with an onmouseover so I'm not sure what could be the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into using jquery? It's design to handle what you're doing more easily. Why reinvent the wheel? And why put event handlers in the DOM?????

Comment: Is your script loaded before or after the div is loaded?

Comment: -frenchie  I thought about using jQuery but I've never used it before.  I might have to look into it though.  The end goal is more complicated but I simplified it down for this post and so that I could try to isolate what was going wrong.


-Asad I load the script before anything in the HTML is loaded.

Comment: @determinedto3d Have you tried using `addEventListener`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
element = document.getElementById('rightScrollRegion');
element.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
    this.style.background = "#0000ff";
});
element.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
    this.style.background = "#ff0000";
});
```

Avoid using inline event handlers. Use the `addEventListener` method to attach event listeners to elements.

You can try this here: http://jsfiddle.net/gkvq8/

Comment: This seemed to work as well.  Thank you!  Is there a reason inline Event Handlers are bad?

Comment: @determinedto3d Yes, they bulk up your HTML and are hard to maintain, and are antithetical to separation of concerns.

Answer (score 2):

your function is opposed to the original function javascript
so change the function name like this:

```
<div language="javascript" onmouseout="funcTwo()" onmouseover="funcOne()" id="rightScrollRegion" class="ScrollRegion"></div>
```

and this

```
function funcOne(){
        document.getElementById('rightScrollRegion').style.backgroundColor = "#0000ff";
    }
    function funcTwo(){
        document.getElementById('rightScrollRegion').style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
    }
```

Comment: So I tried that and is still not calling the external function.  onmouseover="this.style.background = '#0000ff'" isn't really the issue though ... its the onmouseover="scrollLeft();" ...

Comment: your function is opposite with original JS function, so change the function name, don't use `scrollLeft()` and `scrollRight()`

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  I wasn't aware there was a function called that already.  Thank you so much!

Comment: This (faid's) should be the answer I think. It correctly identified the problem as opposed to just offering a potentially better stylistic option. It might be the combination of using an existing name and putting that in an external file, since you can otherwise redefine names.

Comment: [clarifying earlier comment since ran out of edit time...] This (faid's) should be the answer I think. It correctly identified the problem as opposed to just offering a potentially better stylistic option. The problem might have been the combination of re-using an existing name and putting that new definition in an external file (since you can otherwise redefine names) so that it wasn't seen at the time of binding.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

here is the HTML Element:

```
<button onmouseover="mousein(event)" onmouseout="mouseout(event)">hello</button>
```

and the functions:

```
function mousein(event){
    event.target.style.background="#FF0000";
}

function mouseout(event){
    event.target.style.background="#FFFFFF";
}
```

You should access the element by using the 'event' object. There are better ways to do this, you should research about 'unobstrusive' javascript. [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-unobtrusive/)

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It will make your life a whole lot easier and your code a whole lot more flexible.

To use the jQuery library just include this in your HMTL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Something like this will do:

```
$('div').mouseover(function() {
    $('div#rightScrollRegion').attr("style","background-color:#0000ff;");
});

$('div').mouseout(function() {
    $('div#rightScrollRegion').attr("style","background-color:#ff0000;");
});
```

Ideally you would use `addClass` and `removeClass` to change the background colours of the div's, however this is merely a simple example solution.

Comment: Seriously? 32kB solution for a problem of a couple of bytes?

Comment: @Teemu 1.5 years later and with a whole lot more experience under my belt, I see this is an unnecessary use of jQuery, +1

Comment: You're wellcome : D. Looks like I've a typo in my comment, should be 92 kB ; ).

Comment: Probably were referencing the minified and gzipped size :)